# DAX - How To Filter Table Based on Another Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I filter one table based off another in PowerBI? I tried using MERGE to inner join the data using ManufacturuerPartKey and TxDate but I kept on receiving the error "Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation. Details: [List]"

Is there another way I can accomplish this?

Table 1 :

```
 Manufacturer  PartNo     TxDate     TxStatus      ErrorCode     ManufacturerPartKey
  ABC             123    9/29/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
  ABC             123    9/30/2020   Fail         CodeInvalid     ABC-123
  ABC             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-123
  ABC             789    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     ABC-789   
  ABC             567    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-567
  XYZ             567    9/29/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
  XYZ             567    9/30/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
  XYZ             789    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        XYZ-789
  LMO             456    9/29/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
  LMO             456    9/30/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
  EFG             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            EFG-123
  QRS             123    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/2/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/3/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             123    10/4/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             567    10/4/2020   Success      null            QRS-567
```

Table 2:

```
 Manufacturer  PartNo     TxDate      ManufacturerPartKey
  ABC             123    10/1/2020      ABC-123
  ABC             789    10/1/2020      ABC-789   
  ABC             567    10/1/2020      ABC-567
  XYZ             567    9/30/2020      XYZ-567
  XYZ             789    10/1/2020      XYZ-789
  LMO             456    9/30/2020      LMO-456
  EFG             123    10/1/2020      EFG-123
  QRS             123    10/4/2020      QRS-123
  QRS             567    10/4/2020      QRS-567
```

Expected Output:

```
 Manufacturer  PartNo     TxDate     TxStatus      ErrorCode     ManufacturerPartKey
  ABC             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-123
  ABC             567    10/1/2020   Success      null            ABC-567
  ABC             789    10/1/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     ABC-789   
  XYZ             567    9/30/2020   Fail         LoadFail        XYZ-567
  XYZ             789    10/1/2020   Fail         APIFault        XYZ-789
  LMO             456    9/30/2020   Fail         APIFault        LMO-456
  EFG             123    10/1/2020   Success      null            EFG-123
  QRS             123    10/4/2020   Fail         PartInvalid     QRS-123
  QRS             567    10/4/2020   Success      null            QRS-567
```

Comment: You can use Measure/Custom Column to filter out all un necessary data from the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply this solution:

https://www.biinsight.com/quick-tips-how-to-filter-a-column-by-a-column-from-a-different-query-in-power-query/

This work as SQL where statement  Column1 in (select column2 from AnotherTable )

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"PREVIOUS_STEP", each List.Contains(#"REFERENCED_TABLE"[REFERENCED_COLUMN], [COLUMN_TO_BE_FILTERED]))
```

And here code example(i import your table as two excel file):

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\tab1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"TxDate", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(#"Tabl2"[ManufacturerPartKey], [ManufacturerPartKey]) and List.Contains(#"Tabl2"[TxDate], [TxDate]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

here is the most interesting part:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(#"Tabl2"[ManufacturerPartKey], [ManufacturerPartKey]) and List.Contains(#"Tabl2"[TxDate], [TxDate]))
```

Comment: I actually saw that article but didn't implement it until you suggested it. I tried it and it was running for an hour before I stopped it from completing because it only output ~1,300 records out of ~230,000 over an hour so it seems very slow. Thanks a lot for your help though, I definitely appreciate your knowledge and have learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create the same two tables with the same data and did merge queries as new (2nd table **Left outer MERGE** with the 1st table) using **ManufacturuerPartKey** and **TxDate** and I got a new table containing the result you wanted without any errors

[image]

and then expanded **TxStatus** and **ErrorCode** in the 2nd table from the first one. and I got the following:

[image]

doesn't this table contain what you wanted?

Comment: My apologies. Yes that is correct but I should have mentioned that the datasets posted above are just sample datasets. While structure is the same, I wasn't able to use the MERGE transformation feature with my dataset without getting the "too many elements in the enumeration error" which I mentioned in my original post. I suspect it might be due to the fact that I'm working in a DEV environment and there are A LOT of duplicates which is why I wanted to see if there was another way without using merge. Maybe I should request for a cleanup so that I can only work off of clean data...